# XSD Self Referencing issues

Tags: xml, xsd, odata

We're creating our own schema from an OData XML to make it more simple and generic to be able to use by our partners.  However, I stumbled on this issue where it's calling its own type (self-referencing)  and I can't figure out a way to go around this issue.

Here's the snippet, any thoughts?

```
<xsd:element name="User" type="userType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="userType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="customManagerList">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Custom Manager</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="customManager" type="userType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Just add a minOccurs="0" to your customManager element particle and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

So far, I see no problem at all. Just enclosed your snippet in `<xsd:schema>` tags, e.g.:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</xsd:schema>
```

and passed through validation. It works. A complexType is allowed to reference itself.

Comment: It is true that the schema is valid as per the XSD spec; however, for all practical reasons, **it is invalid** simply because there is no way one could create a valid XML instance according to it. To make it work, one needs to add minOccurs="0" to the customManager element particle. Some validators I've seen are correctly catching this impossibility, and report it as an error.